# What prevents gcc from optimizing this function?

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization

In one of my classes we were discussing how compilers are quite good at optimizing our own terrible code.

I was testing this out and wrote the following two quite horrible functions.

```
unsigned int add2 (unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned int sum = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}

unsigned int mul2 (unsigned int a, unsigned int b) {
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        result = add2(result, b);
    }
    return result;
}
```

When compiled with the `-O3` or `-Ofast` the `add2` function is compiled straight to a simple addition. The `mul2` function however is a terrible mess of instructions and branches. I wouldn't consider this interesting on its own, *but* if you change that call to `add2` to a simple addition of `result` and `b` the compiler optimizes it straight to a multiplication instruction.

This seems weird because the compiler essentially considers `add2` to be an addition, and the compiler considers `mul2` a multiplication, why can't it optimize it correctly when they are combined?

[Here is a link to godbolt sketch](https://godbolt.org/z/0oxjTP) showing this more explicitly.

Edit:

I was looking at this more and interestingly compiling to optimize space with `-Os` compiles to a standard multiplication instruction. This seems to imply that the other version is faster which doesn't seem to make any sense.

[Here is a a version](https://godbolt.org/z/6f7rl6) with output showing that the the code is correct in its current form at least for trivial inputs.

Comment: The code is pretty good - it's doing exactly as you ask in an optimised way. However you have a logic error in mul2. Consider the output when the code is corrected: https://godbolt.org/z/5wzPlX

Comment: @RichardHodges I've added a link to a version that produces a console output for testing and as you will see changing to += produces the incorrect result as result and b are already being added together in the add2 function

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I misread. Interestingly you also get shorter code with -O2 than with -O3. It looks as if -O3 is preferring to unroll loops rather than replace multiple adds with a multiply.

Comment: Quite interesting indeed. However I would nhot say "a terrible mess of instructions", as it is just inlining the function `add2`(I looked with ARM compiler, as I am more fmailiar with it). Might just be a limitation of GCC optimization algorithm but it's hard to understand the root cause.  In my experience it is often difficult to understand the optimisations that are done, even if obviously 99% of the time they make sense

Comment: @RichardHodges I didn't think to check that, that's quite weird. I think the strangest though is how it compiles with -Os as it shows it can compile to a single instruction but for some reason chooses the other.

Comment: The replacement, whether for addition or multiplication, is done in the SCCP pass. When add2 (not optimized yet) is inlined in mul2, SCCP does manage to optimize the addition, but then we would probably need a couple passes to clean things up and then re-run SCCP to optimize the multiplication. This is not done because it would increase compile-time for an infrequent gain. You could still file an enhancement request on gcc's bugzilla if you want, maybe there are simple tricks that would let SCCP optimize the outer loop as well.